# Макрос для excel: выделение слов цветом

Tags: vba, excel

Привет, помогите разобраться с макросом для excel, нужно для работы.
Есть макрос:

```
Sub FindAndSelect()
   Dim strStartAddr As String ' Хранит координаты первого найденного значения
   Dim rgResult As Range

   ' Поиск первого входжения искомого слова
   Set rgResult = Range("A1:A10000").Find("слон", , xlValues)
   If Not rgResult Is Nothing Then
      ' Сохраним адрес найденной ячейки (чтобы контролировать зацикливание поиска)
      strStartAddr = rgResult.Address
   End If
   Do While Not rgResult Is Nothing
      ' Обработка результата поиска
      rgResult.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)

      ' Новый поиск
      Set rgResult = Range("A1:A10000").FindNext(rgResult)
      If rgResult.Address = strStartAddr Then
         ' Поиск завершен
         Exit Do
      End If
   Loop
End Sub
```

Этот макрос ищет по столбцу А с 1 по 10000 строку, слово "слон" и выделяет ячейку цветом.
Мне бы хотелось его доработать так, чтобы макрос искал не одно слово "слон", а искал еще несколько слов, и закрашивал их разными цветами, к примеру: "слон" закрашивал красным, "белку" закрашивал зеленым, "шмеля" закрашивал серым.

Подскажите идеи для реализации этой задачи, спасибо.

Comment: ну, а в чём проблема? почему не выходит параметризировать код по слону и цвету? что вы пробовали?

Comment: А действительно нужно писать макрос для этих целей? Чем не устраивает условное форматирование?

Answer (score 1):

Условное форматирование не всегда применимо.

*Find* медленная функция.

Попробуем циклом.

```
Option Explicit

Sub FindAndSelect()
Dim Rng As Range
Dim n
    With Worksheets("1")
        Set Rng = .Range("A2:D100")

        For Each n In Rng
            Select Case n
                Case "слон"
                    n.Interior.Color = 255
                Case "белка"
                    n.Interior.Color = 5296274
                Case "енот"
                    n.Interior.Color = 15773696
            End Select
        Next n
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Прелесть условного форматирования в его скорости, форматируется только видимая область на экране, при этом фактически формат ячейки не меняется. К сожалению, действительно, не все можно им сделать...